# Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' Object required: '[undefined]'

Tags: vba, visual-basic-6, vbs

Tenho uma rotina q estava funcionando normalmete no IE 8, quando atualizado para o IE 11 ele me apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
>
> Object required: '[undefined]'
>
> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
>
> Object required: '[undefined]'
>
> /qualidade/cadastros.old/upl_conf.asp, line 30

Segue script:

```
' Chamando Funções, que fazem o Upload funcionar
byteCount = Request.TotalBytes
RequestBin = Request.BinaryRead(byteCount)
Set UploadRequest = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
BuildUploadRequest RequestBin

' Recuperando os Dados Digitados ----------------------
num_rc = UploadRequest.Item("TXTrc").Item("Value")            <--- Linha 30

' Tipo de arquivo que esta sendo enviado
tipo_arq = UploadRequest.Item("arq").Item("ContentType")

' Caminho completo dos arquivos enviados
caminho_arq = UploadRequest.Item("arq").Item("FileName")

' Nome dos arquivos enviados
nome_arq = Right(caminho_arq,Len(caminho_arq)-InstrRev(caminho_arq,"\"))
```

Vocês teriam alguma ideia de como solucionar este caso?

Comment: Sem saber a origem de `TXTrc` não dá para responder essa pergunta.